# What is the name of this normal subgroup of the free group?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation

Given the free group $F_S$, we can define a normal subgroup of $F_S$ as follows. For a given element $w \in F_S$ and $s \in S$, define "the count of $s$", $c_s(w)$, as the number of times $s$ appears in $w$ as written as a word. Then the subgroup of $F_S$ defined as 
$$N_s = \{w \in F_S \;|\; c_s(w)-c_{s^{-1}}(w) = 0 \}$$
is normal in $F_S$.

This normal subgroup must have a name. What is it? I am unfamiliar with group presentations and couldn't find one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly the normal subgroup generated by $S\setminus\{s\}$.  Clearly $N_s$ contains $S\setminus\{s\}$.  Conversely, if $N$ is any normal subgroup that contains $S\setminus\{s\}$, then any element of $N_s$ maps to the identity in the quotient $F_S/N$ (since all the elements of $S$ except for $s$ map to the identity and so can be removed from the word), so $N_s\subseteq N$.

Comment: This is very interesting! I am having trouble understanding what this map $N_s$ to $F_S/N$ is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's just the quotient map $F_S\to F_S/N$.